# Unintentional outline around canvas triangles

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas

I am making a 3d engine, and noticed an outline around every shape that is drawn. I've tried a few ways to get rid of this, like `image-rendering: pixelated;` in the css for the canvas, `ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;`, and I also tried adding my own outline, but that was too laggy. Is there any way to fix this?

[image: plane made of triangles with an unwanted outline]

I've searched google and asked chatGPT, but they all went straight to what I've already tried. Please help.

You can recreate this problem with any shape with a line that isn't vertical or horozontal, ex:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(200, 200);
    ctx.lineTo(300, 200);
    ctx.lineTo(300, 300);
    ctx.lineTo(200, 200);
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(200, 200);
    ctx.lineTo(200, 300);
    ctx.lineTo(300, 300);
    ctx.lineTo(200, 200);
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    
    //the triangles share two of the same points, yet there is still an outline/gap
```

```css
* {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    canvas {
        background: black;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width=500 height=500></canvas>

</html>
```

Comment: are you setting `ctx.strokeStyle`?

Comment: "they all went straight to what I've already tried" okay so [what were the things you already tried?](/help/how-to-ask) If you tried a bunch of things, show those (in [mcve] form, ideally) in your post, and talk about how they didn't work. And also remember that ChatGPT is not a learning tool. It's a _story writing_ tool, and it will make up nonsense if it means the story sounds reasonable. Even if it yields code that works, the odds that it's _good_ code are incredibly low.

Comment: @ggorlen I added a snippet into the question, and the outline I added was the same color as the poly, but was too slow.

Comment: See [JavaScript - Gap between triangles when wire-frame is removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43236289/javascript-gap-between-triangles-when-wire-frame-is-removed)

Comment: Note that there is a [mesh-2D API](https://github.com/fserb/canvas2D/blob/master/spec/mesh2d.md) proposal that is being baked. Hopefully this will come to live soon enough and should help with your use case.

Answer (score -1):

That line is drawn by the `beginPath` `closePath`, omit them and it's fine.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.moveTo(200, 200);
ctx.lineTo(300, 200);
ctx.lineTo(300, 300);
ctx.lineTo(200, 200);
ctx.fill();

ctx.moveTo(200, 200);
ctx.lineTo(200, 300);
ctx.lineTo(300, 300);
ctx.lineTo(200, 200);
ctx.fill();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

canvas {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width=500 height=500></canvas>
```